# Update Files Using Google Drive API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm telling you my problem, I'm trying to create a code in PHP that uploads files to Google Drive and so far so good, but I also want that if it detects that I'm uploading a file that already exists, it updates it through version control. from Google Drive so the file only updates its content without affecting the ID it has.

```
<?php

require 'conexion.php';
include 'api-google/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=sigsac-c1a7b31e7aa5.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']);

try {

    $nombre = $_FILES['archivos']['name'];
    $extension = $_FILES['archivos']['type'];

    $service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

    // Verificar si el archivo ya existe en Google Drive
    $existingFile = null;
    $results = $service->files->listFiles(array('q' => "name='$nombre'"));
    foreach ($results->getFiles() as $file) {
        $existingFile = $file;
        break;
    }

    if ($existingFile) {
        // Actualizar el contenido del archivo existente
        $file_path = $_FILES['archivos']['tmp_name'];
        $content = file_get_contents($file_path);

        $updatedFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $updatedFile->setId($existingFile->getId());
        $updatedFile->setName($existingFile->getName());

        $service->files->update(
            $existingFile->getId(),
            $updatedFile,
            array(
                'data' => $content,
                'mimeType' => $existingFile->getMimeType(),
                'uploadType' => 'media'
            )
        );

        echo "Archivo actualizado: <a href='https://drive.google.com/open?id=" . $existingFile->getId() . "' target='_blank'>$nombre</a>";
    } else {
        // Continuar con la carga del archivo si no existe
        $file_path = $_FILES['archivos']['tmp_name'];
        $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setName($nombre);

        $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mime_type = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);

        $file->setParents(array("1wCtnAxZE3sG6sHtqbZJ45njIAtPW6NZb"));
        $file->setDescription("Archivo cargado desde PHP");
        $file->setMimeType($mime_type);

        $resultado = $service->files->create(
            $file,
            array(
                'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
                'mimeType' => $mime_type,
                'uploadType' => 'media'
            )
        );

        $ruta = 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=' . $resultado->id;

        $sql = "INSERT INTO archivos(nombre, ruta, extension) VALUES ('$nombre', '$ruta', '$mime_type')";
        
        $mysqli->query($sql);

        echo '<a href="' . $ruta . '" target="_blank">'.$resultado->name.'</a>';
    }
        
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $gs) {
    $mensaje = json_decode($gs->getMessage());
    echo $mensaje->error->message;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

My previous PHP code is able to detect existing files but does not update I get the following error "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable." I appreciate your help.

Comment: You should add information about the google drive SDK you are using (cos your codes shows you are using one).

Comment: Otherwise you can check the API for file update which allows you to update a file by providing the ID: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files/update

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `but I also want that if it detects that I'm uploading a file that already exists, it updates it through version control. from Google Drive so the file only updates its content without affecting the ID it has.`. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.